# ng-payment-card : expiration year's dropdown doesn't contain proper options

Tags: angular, npm-package

I'm using ng-payment-card in my project and I had a serious issue in the expiration year's dropdown list, because the options contain only this year + a few years later only.
anyone found a solution for this problem??

[image: ng-payment-card package]

Comment: What's the issue and what are you trying to achieve. Explain the issue you are having

Comment: @penleychan I think the issue is clear, I have a package to simulate a payment card and as normal the card's expiration year could be after 8 years from now, but in this package the maximum year is after 4 years from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The years appear to be generated [here](https://github.com/Bartosz-D3V/ng-payment-card/blob/3de3f9c67b8205907f3b430461bc2c6bcc7580e5/projects/ng-payment-card/src/lib/service/payment-card.service.ts#L44):

```
public static getYears(): Array<number> {
    const years: Array<number> = [];
    const year = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (let i = -2; i < 5; i++) {
      years.push(year + i);
    }
    return years;
  }
}
```

As you can see, that `-2` is hardcoded. I think the best you can do is alter your local copy of the source; although that's probably inadvisable.